# Server blocked in readUTF() function

Tags: java, server, client

I'm trying to share informations successively between my client and my server but it get stuck when the server is reading.

First the client send some information about himself (id and str string variables)

**Client**

```
out.writeUTF(id+" "+str);
out.flush();
System.out.println("Do you want a room ?");
System.out.println("These are the available room");
String a4;
while((a4=in.readUTF()) != null)
    System.out.println(a4);
System.out.println("Pick one"); // It doesn't print that
sc4 = new Scanner(System.in);
String str4 = sc4.next();
out.writeUTF(str4);
out.flush();
```

**Server**

```
out.writeUTF(Room.getAllRooms());
out.flush();
System.out.println("Before read");
String res = in.readUTF(); // stuck here
System.out.println("After read");
.
.
.
```

The printing of all the rooms works great in the client. But just after I can't access to the printing "Pick one".

The server is reading nothing, but why the server is reading first and the client don't write first ?

(I simplified the code, in fact i'm using a master/slave architecture using threads)

**Update** : Problem solved, please read the response bellow. (readUTF() never turns null)

Comment: It looks like you are trying to do too much in your `while` condition.  Try splitting it into two parts so you are checking the stream, not the string.

Answer (score 1):

You are not 'stuck' but *blocked*, and not in 'read' but in `readUTF()`, and the reason for that is that the peer has neither sent anything nor closed the connection. This is expected behaviour. You have *one* `writeUTF()` and a never-ending *loop* of `readUTF()`s. Have a think about your application protocol.

BTW you have a bug:

```
while((a4=in.readUTF()) != null)
    System.out.println(a4);
```

`readUTF()` *never* returns null. When the peer closes the connection it will throw `EOFException`.

Comment: Thanks I understand now, do you have an idea on how I can fix that ?

Comment: I can get the number of rooms and loop on this number but is there an easiest way to do that ?

Comment: I fixed it by removing all the "\n" except the last one in a4 String. In this way I get the entire string without any loop. Thanks !

Comment: Adding `\n` was never going to cause you to get the entire string in a loop. One `writeUTF()` = one `readUTF()`. Strange assumption.